# Adding Video Field in Django

Tags: python, django, video

I want be add a video field in the django.I am not able to add it.
How can I add a videofield in django in the admin portion like that of ImageFeild?

Comment: Why can't you add it?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 15):

So Django doesn't have a `VideoField` similar to `ImageField`

So what you have to use is a `FileField`

Here is my short example on the same

```
class UserDoc(models.Model):
    
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images_uploaded',null=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos_uploaded',null=True,
validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['MOV','avi','mp4','webm','mkv'])])
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

Notice that I added a [FileExtensionValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#fileextensionvalidator) which checks that only these file extensions are valid.

You can, of course, add all the extensions you feel for your use case.

Validating the file extension isn't enough but that is the least amount of security you could provide for ensuring that the files are of that format.

Answer (score 3):

You question is not so clear, if you want to add a video that will be saved on the server, you need to create a folder in your root project you can name it media, create a view that will save the uploaded videos if it will be uploaded by your users and then add a video player on the template and as a "src" use the url of the video.
You can read this for better explanation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the FileField in the same way you use the ImageField